# How to generate unique ids on a repeated function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function called twice:

```
function (data) {
   $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {    
                  var $items = $('<div class="col-sm-4 grid-item"><div class="thumbnail"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_'+i+'" value="valuable" id="thing_'+i+'"/><label for="thing_'+i+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></label></div></div>');`enter code here`
```

It generates checkboxes and I am generating the identifier `name` `for` and `id` with the `i`, giving me:

```
thing_1
thing_2
thing_3
```

The problem is that when I run the function the second time, the `i` starts again, resulting in duplicated `ids` and `name` and `for`

Comment: Do they each need to have a unique identifiers? That is a little bit of an anti-pattern in most cases. A better alternative is to give all the elements the same structure and use DOM traversal to find the relevant elements as needed.

Comment: well yeah they should all have a unique identifier as they are checkboxes

Comment: That's no reason alone to need a unique identifier

Comment: if i remove for and name and id they won't check as checkboxes and not be valid

Comment: In that case just wrap the `<label>` around the `<input>`

Comment: i cannot as the images are  replacing the check boxes

Comment: What images are you referring to?

Comment: check the code in the question, there is an image replacing the chekcboxes

Comment: There is now you edited it in ;) Either way, you really don't need unique attributes and you can still wrap the input in a label without affecting the image - see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/rytcz9e2/

Comment: yeah there was at first then i removed it to make the code shorter for SO but then you commented so I put it again :)

Comment: instead of i could you use getTime() ?

Comment: @BryanDellinger mm that would be an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript#8228308):

```
var uniqueId = (function() {
  var counter = 0;

  return function(prefix) {
    counter++;
    return prefix ? prefix + '' + counter : counter;
  }
})();

console.log(uniqueId()); // 1
console.log(uniqueId()); // 2
console.log(uniqueId('thing_')); // thing_3
console.log(uniqueId('thing_')); // thing_4
```

You would integrate it in your code like this:

```
function (data) {
  $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
    var $items = $('<div class="col-sm-4 grid-item">'.concat(
      '<div class="thumbnail">',
      '<input type="checkbox" name="', uniq, '" value="valuable" id="', uniq, '" />',
      '<label for="', uniq, '">',
        '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '">',
      '</label>',
    '</div>',
  '</div>'));
```

I broke your huge HTML mess on multiply lines using `String.prototype.concat`

Comment: could you elaborate it to reflect the code in the question?